# Way to create more manageable array when looping through an array with multiple joins?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, join

I have an array that I am passing to my view and it's joined with multiple tables. Let's call this array `Submissions`. All `submissions` contain `SubmissionVote`s and a typical data `submission` object looks like this:

```
 [1] => Array
        (
            [Submission] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 17
                    [title] => Yo mama so fat when she went to the movies she sat next to everyone
                    [source] => http://www.ahajokes.com/ym01.html
                    [slug] => yo-mama-so-fat-when-she-went-to-the-movies-she-sat-next
                    [category] => funny
                    [created] => 2012-09-26 21:00:35
                    [id] => 104
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 17
                    [username] => bob_cobb
                )

            [SubmissionsVote] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 323
                            [user_id] => 2
                            [submission_id] => 104
                            [vote_type] => up
                            [when] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                            [voted_ip] => 842844107
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 322
                            [user_id] => 17
                            [submission_id] => 104
                            [vote_type] => up
                            [when] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                            [voted_ip] => 1163843117
                        )

                )

            [SubmissionThumbnails] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [submission_id] => 104
                            [original] => http://www.ahajokes.com/g/smlogo.gif
                            [extension] => jpg
                            [slug] => http://www.ahajokes.com/g/smlogo.gif
                        )

                )

        )
```

Right now I'm just doing a `foreach` through this in my view and grabbing: `$submission['Submission']['id']`, `$submission['Submission']['category']` and other useful stuff from it. This is all fine, but I'd like to somehow be able to just make a new object (or something equally as intuitive) that has the number of up `vote_type` and number of down `vote_type` so that I can just be like `$submission['Submission']['upVotes']` / `$submission['Submission']['downVotes']`.

I'm doing the join in CakePHP and here is my query:

```
        $this->find('all', array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'Submission.user_id',
                    'Submission.title',
                    'Submission.source',
                    'Submission.slug',
                    'Submission.category',
                    'Submission.created',
                    'User.id',
                    'User.username'),
                'order' => 'Submission.created DESC'));
```

The only reason I want to do this is because going through and having to add up all upvotes and downvotes within my view would be quite the pain, not to mention pretty sloppy.

How can I improve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using **virtual fields**: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html.

In your `Submission` model, you would have something similar to:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'up_count' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM submission_votes AS up_count WHERE submission_id = Submission.id AND vote_type = "up"',
    'down_count' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM submission_votes AS down_count WHERE submission_id = Submission.id AND vote_type="down"',
);
```

In the above example, `submission_votes` is your database table name for your `SubmissionVote` model.  Be sure to heed the warning: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#limitations-of-virtualfields.

If you just want to manipulate the data array, another option might be to use the something from the `Hash` class, such as `Hash::reduce`.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash::reduce